# Use Vue data in stylesheet

Tags: sass, vue.js, vuejs2

How can I access Vue data in my stylesheet?

I am writing in Sass, but I don't think that it has anything to do with the issue.

I tried this, but it didnt work:

```
#app
  background-color: {{ myText }}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stylesheets are not dynamic like the DOM. There is no updating them. You can use the [`class` and `style` bindings](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html) to affect the styling of your page by changing element styling or applying different classes to elements.